# ESP12 with WS2812B first led always stays on

Tags: arduino, esp8266, ws2812b

I'm making a custom remote with esp12 and 3x WS2812B led, while making the main code i discovered a problem, the first led in the series always stays on when trying to execute an example NEOPIXEL code "simple", the leds are connected to the ESP12 PIN 2, which i found out was the same pin that controls the inbuilt led, as it stays on all the time too with the first led but the next two led work correctly and are turning on and off as they should.

I tried maybe desoldering the inbuilt led on the ESP12 but that didn't change anything.
Tried maybe changing the led count in the code that didn't help.

What else could i try to fix this and get the led to work as intended?

EDIT:
Schematic:
[image]
Sample code im using to test:

```cpp
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#ifdef __AVR__
 #include <avr/power.h> // Required for 16 MHz Adafruit Trinket
#endif
#define PIN        2 // On Trinket or Gemma, suggest changing this to 1
#define NUMPIXELS 3 // Popular NeoPixel ring size
Adafruit_NeoPixel pixels(NUMPIXELS, PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);                              
#define DELAYVAL 500 // Time (in milliseconds) to pause between pixels
void setup() {
 
#if defined(__AVR_ATtiny85__) && (F_CPU == 16000000)
  clock_prescale_set(clock_div_1);
#endif
  pixels.begin(); // INITIALIZE NeoPixel strip object (REQUIRED)
}
void loop() {
  pixels.clear(); // Set all pixel colors to 'off'
  for(int i=0; i<NUMPIXELS; i++) { // For each pixel...
    pixels.setPixelColor(i, pixels.Color(0, 10, 0));
    pixels.show();   
    delay(DELAYVAL); 
  }
}
```

Comment: rewrite the code

Comment: Double check your code.

Comment: You show neither your code nor a schematic or even a picture of your setup. There's no way for us to help you except by giving very generic advice.

Comment: Added the example code im using and my schematic